# From a list of numbers I want to get those ids that are not present in the table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a list of IDs that I want to check if they are in the `employee` table.
I want to display only those that are not in the table.

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;
EMPLOYEEID|FIRSTNAME|LASTNAME
1         | JOHN    | DOE
2         | JANE    | DOE
```

When I run the sql statement below I am hoping to get the IDs not present in employee table.

```
SELECT '1', '2, '3', '4' AS "X1"FROM 
EMPLOYEE WHERE X1 NOT IN (SELECT EMPLOYEEID FROM EMPLOYEE);
```

Comment: You can't use the values as columns to do what you want, you have to do `select x1 from (selec 1 as x1 ... UNION ALL select 2 .... UNION ALL select 3 .....) where x1 not in ..... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform those numbers to a subquery, then select the ones that not exists in your table:

```
with t as
(
select 1 X1 from dual
union
select 2 X1 from dual
union
select 3 X1 from dual
)
SELECT X1 FROM t
WHERE X1 NOT IN (SELECT EMPLOYEEID FROM EMPLOYEE)
```

If you have a big list of IDs and you will perform some more complex queries, it might be worth looking into creating a [temporary table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#i1006400) to store them, then use the temporary table instead of the subquery I suggested.

Comment: Could you write the whole query please ?